# Adding space between navbar logo and first nav link

Tags: html, header, uinavigationbar, navbar

[Nav Bar Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RXDj.png) sorry for my bad English. I am trying to add a bit space after logo so that logo stays on the left corner and the first nav links pushed on the left side not totally left but a bit more to the right.
I copied the exact same HTML and CSS code.

```
<nav class="nav navbar-default navbar">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-header ">
        <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="C:\Users\usama\Downloads\logo.jpg" alt=""></a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="navbarp"><a href="#"><i class="active fa fa-book fa-xs"></i><br><p></p>About</a></li>
                <li class="navbarp"><a href="#"><i class="fal fa-registered"></i><br><p></p>Admissions</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="navbarp"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i><br><p></p>sign up</a></li>
                <li class="navbarp"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i><br><p></p>login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (padding is added to the right of the logo):

```
<a class="navbar-brand" style="padding-right:15px">
    <img src="C:\Users\usama\Downloads\logo.jpg" alt="" />
</a>
```

Or (padding is added to the left of the nav bar):

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" style="padding-left:15px">
```

Also, check your `<li>` tags. You currently have:

```
<li class="navbarp"><a href="#"><i class="active fa fa-book fa-xs"></i><br><p></p>About</a></li>
```

Note how the heading "about" is outside of the `<p></p>` tags.

I suspect you'd want it to be formatted it this way:

```
<li class="navbarp"><a href="#"><i class="active fa fa-book fa-xs"></i><p>About</p></a></li>
```

With the word being correctly in the `<p></p>` tag, you might not need the `<br>`